# Send a get request to a different website on link click?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, http

I have a method:

```
  def getRequest(link)
    require 'net/http'

    url = URI.parse(@target + link)
    reqest = Net::HTTP::Get.new(url.to_s)
    response = Net::HTTP.start(url.host, url.port) {|http|
          http.request(request)
    }
    console.log(response)
  end
```

I want a link in a view that would call `getRequest("www.google.com")`, sort of like:

```
<%= link_to 'Test GET request', 'getRequest/link="www.google.com"%>
```

How do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do that. Learn more about Rails. After that try this solution:

```
<%= link_to 'Test GET request', test_users_path(test_link: "www.google.com")%>
```

UsersController:

```
def test
    link = params[:test_link] 
    require 'net/http'

    url = URI.parse(@target + link)
    reqest = Net::HTTP::Get.new(url.to_s)
    response = Net::HTTP.start(url.host, url.port) {|http|
          http.request(request)
    }
    console.log(response)
    redirect_to ...
end
```

Answer (score -1):

The `:target => '_blank'` parameter should be a parameter of `link_to`, whereas you put it in `image_tag` parameters. Modify your code like this:

```
<%= link_to("google", :alt => "Google"), "http://www.google.com", :target => "_blank" %>
```